# Invalid beef hook id: the hooked browser cannot be found in the database?

Tags: xss, beef

So I've just installed `beEF` on my `centOS` server, but so far it hasn't been working on any page that's not in the same browser that I'm logged into. The `beEF` admin panel only works on the demo pages that are on the same IP address as the server.
Can anyone help me figure it out? Whenever I try to use it on a different site, it either doesn't show up on my hooked browsers, or this error shows up:

> "[EVENTS] Invalid beef hook id: the hooked browser cannot be found in the database".

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your database (sqlite by default) is damaged... or incorrect after an update. You can try to remove the sqlite file. I'm not sure of the location in CentOS... In my Kali Linux is on `/usr/share/beef-xss/db` and there you can delete de beef.db file (or rename it to beef.db.old as backup). And then you can start the framework using `-x` parameter which seems to re-create the database file.

You can also modify the `config.yaml` file to set debug mode to true and http to true too in order to show more info on console. Maybe you can see the problem with this. Usually are problems related to ruby gems.